# Dyanamic mutation dplyr

Tags: r

I want to dynamically subtract values using mutate but not sure how to do it. Below is an exemplar image of what I would like to do:
[image]

Staring from the 2nd row of the table, Col C = previous Col C element - current Col B element, i.e. 5- 1 = 4. Similarly 3rd row of Col C = 2nd element of Col C (that we just mutated) -  3rd element of Col B, i.e. 4-2 = 2. Thus, nth element of Col C = (n-1)th of Col C - nth of Col B. I already have values in Col B, but Col C values are being mutated dynamically. So the current mutated value for Col C depends on the previous mutated value. I am using lag command (dplyr) to subtract the values. Can anyone help with this dynamic mutation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: Try `df1 %>% mutate(new = lag(ColC, default = first(ColB))  - ColB)`

Answer (score 0):

We can subtract the cumulative sum from the second value in `ColB` onwards with the 1st value in `ColB`. This can be done in base R

```
df$ColC <- with(df, c(ColB[1], ColB[1] - cumsum(ColB[-1])))
df
#  ColB ColC
#1    5    5
#2    1    4
#3    2    2
#4    3   -1
#5    4   -5
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(ColC = c(first(ColB),first(ColB) - cumsum(ColB[-1])))
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(ColB = c(5, 1:4))
```